# How do I send a PUT request using the SIM800L (Firebase)

Tags: http, curl, firebase-realtime-database, put, at-command

I'm using the SIM800L module to send temperature data to the Firebase realtime database. I am able to successfully POST and GET using the HTTPACTION AT commands.

I have an entry in the realtime database that I would like to occasionally toggle the value between 0 and 1. If I use the POST command I end up having a new entry in my database every time I try change the value.

I have been reading the REST API document but I don't understand how to implement the following example using AT commands and the SIM800L:

```
curl -X PUT -d '{ "first": "Jack", "last": "Sparrow" }' \
    'https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/users/jack/name.json'
```

This is taken from the following page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/

I'm very new to storing data in the cloud and client-server communication so please excuse my ignorance, this is all very new and confusing to me at the moment.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried `curl -X PATCH -d '{ "first": "Jack", "last": "Sparrow" }' \
    'https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/users/jack/name.json'` ? - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/#section-patch

Answer (score 1):

`PUT` is not available, for details see the SIMCom documentation
[section 11.2.5 AT+HTTPACTION HTTP Method Action](https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/images/2/20/SIM800_Series_AT_Command_Manual_V1.09.pdf).

A pragmatic solution would be to use the SIMCom's [TCP/IP Application Toolkit](https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/images/2/20/SIM800_Series_AT_Command_Manual_V1.09.pdf) and implement the `PUT` request yourself.

[The TCP/IP Application note](https://simcom.ee/documents/SIM800x/SIM800%20Series_TCPIP_Application%20Note_V1.02.pdf) is a good reference. See also [these application notes](https://simcom.ee/documents/?dir=SIM800x).